# Calling cross controller function

Tags: function, view, controller, sapui5

I have two pairs of controller and view. The first view contains a list of items, while the in second shows some details of a specific item. What I want to achieve is that a click on one list item, the function onSelect should call second controller of detail view and update its content with the selected list item.

So far I have following code:

```
//first list controller
onSelect : function () {
var secondController = sap.ui.controller("controller.Detail");
secondController.updateFunction("some text");
}
```

Then in second controller:

```
//second detail-controller
updateFunction: function (someText) {
var view = sap.ui.xmlview("view.Detail");
view.byId("someTextField").setText(someText);
}
```

The problem is that this is not working. It seems that sap.ui.xmlview is not returning the same view which is displayed. 
When I execute following code:

```
var model = view.getModel(model);
console.log(model);
```

within 2 functions of detail controller, but first is called by outside controller and second is called by onInit or function called by detail view event, the id is different.

How can I achieve such a cross-controller function calling with updating content of different view? Or is my approach not proper?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use either the [EventBus](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.EventBus.html) or [Routing](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Router.html) for inter view communication.

**Routing** is nice as it uses the [hash part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (#) of the url to communicate for example an event like the selection of an item (f.e. https://example.com/myUi5App/index.html#/item/123). The user can use the browser history and bookmarks to navigate through your app.
A view can register to the router to be notified when a specific url pattern is matched. The walkthrough in the SAPUI5 Developer Guide does nicely explain routing step by step and in detail [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html) and [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html).

**EventBus** is a global object that can publish arbitrary events. Anyone interested can register to the EventBus. There is an EventBus on the [Component](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html#getEventBus) which you should use if you have a component and a [global EventBus](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html#getEventBus).

Both techniques help decoupling your views. It does not matter if there are one, many or none views listening to the selection change. And it does not matter for the listeners who fired the event.

Answer (score 0):

If both views have been called once you can achieve this via the view (from my opionion, this is quite hacky and should be solved otherway)

```
this.getView().byId("yourViewId").oController.yourMethod();
```

means in your case

```
onSelect : function () {
  var secondController = this.getView().byId("view_id").oController;
  secondController.updateFunction("some text");
}
```

maybe this helps you, he is passing the controller reference which would be a better option: [Calling Controller Function from inside a press handler in sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557886/calling-controller-function-from-inside-a-press-handler-in-sapui5)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1");
```

According to documentation `var view = sap.ui.xmlview("view.Detail");` always creates a new view.

However I am still struggling about specifying id of xmlview. Since "___xmlview1" is dynamicly given name and the number 1 means serial number of views within application. So if I create another view before creation of "view.Detail", the id will point to the new one.

I am creating xmlview like this:

```
<mvc:XMLView viewName="view.Detail"></mvc:XMLView>
```